# f2py doesn't like explicit shaped array in subroutine

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to compile a python module from some Fortran code using `f2py`. The code compiles fine with ifort, but throws up errors when using f2py. Here is the code (it is over two files):

gdat.f90:

```
  MODULE GDAT
  PUBLIC

  INTEGER :: NX, NY

  END MODULE GDAT
```

part.f90:

```
  SUBROUTINE PART(ARR)

  USE GDAT, ONLY: NX, NY
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: ARR(NX,NY)
  PRINT*, ARR

  END SUBROUTINE PART
```

I compile it using `f2py -c gdat.f90 part.f90 -m part`, but I get errors about nx and ny not being defined, e.g.:
    /var/tmp/tmp2hzU6s/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/untitledmodule.c: In function 'f2py_rout_untitled_part':
    /var/tmp/tmp2hzU6s/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/untitledmodule.c:180: error: 'nx' undeclared (first use in this function)

It seems to be a problem with the definition of the explicitly shaped array `ARR`. Like I say, it compiles fine on ifort.

I know this is a simple piece of code and can be written another way, but it is just a test piece that I wrote: I am actually trying to compile a much larger set of fortran modules that have lots of these explicit array definitions in the (using variables from a central module to define the bounds), so I would really like to get this to work rather than rewrite this other code!

Comment: The problem may be that f2py doesn't support array sizes from an `USE` block. Getting to those requires additional Fortran-based wrappers, and I'm not sure it does that. I think you can write your own getters for nx and ny, and use those in a f2py wrapper definition .pyf file. (The rest is left as an exercise, too late for me to think about this today... It also doesn't fit into the margin of this comment box ;)

Comment: Thanks @pv. Sounds like I'm will need to rewrite the code after all! Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this, you have the problem, that the size of arrays has to be dynamic via `ALLOCATABLE` or already fixed with numerical constants or parameters.

In your case, the variables `nx` and `ny` are neither set nor parameters. And if you want to compile your two files separately into modules (with `ifort` and not `f2py`), it should also complain.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a signature file via

```
f2py -m pythmod -h signature.pyf gdat.f90 part.f90
```

and then using it with

```
f2py -c signature.pyf gdat.f90 part.f90 .
```

This creates the file *pythmod.so* .