f2py compiling fails when dimensions are taken from a module
The Fortran code below cannot be compiled with f2py using command
f2py -m ggchemlib -c --fcompiler=gfortran --f90flags="-fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8" --opt="-O5" test.f90
The error message is
/tmp/tmpb4kqj9_4/src.linux-x86_64-3.10/ggchemlibmodule.c:292:16: error: ‘nmole’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  292 |   sat_Dims[0]=(nmole);
      |                ^~~~~

The problem seems to be the way that the variable Sat is declared in subroutine SUPERSAT, where the dimension of Sat is taken from a data module.  Here is test.f90:
module CHEMISTRY
  integer :: NMOLE
end module CHEMISTRY

program main
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  real*8 :: T
  NMOLE = 20
  T = 1000.0
  call CHECK_MELTING(T)
end program main

subroutine CHECK_MELTING(T)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 33, 4931 )
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  call SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
end subroutine CHECK_MELTING

subroutine SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 33, 4931 )
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp),intent(out) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  Sat(1:NMOLE) = 0.q0
end subroutine SUPERSAT

Is there a simple way to fix this?
The following modification would work, but this is not a feasible solution for me, because I want to port a large Fortran code to Python, where taking the dimensions of variables from modules is used all the time.
module CHEMISTRY
  integer :: NMOLE
end module CHEMISTRY

program main
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  real*8 :: T
  NMOLE = 20
  T = 1000.0
  call CHECK_MELTING(T)
end program main

subroutine CHECK_MELTING(T)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 33, 4931 )
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  call SUPERSAT(NMOLE,T,Sat)
end subroutine CHECK_MELTING

subroutine SUPERSAT(NMOLE,T,Sat)
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 33, 4931 )
  integer,intent(in) :: NMOLE
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp),intent(out) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  Sat(1:NMOLE) = 0.q0
end subroutine SUPERSAT


Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. This is an old defect in f2py, you should be able to find older questions about this. The workaround will be a work for you anyway, f2py just does not support this directly. It only supports a subset of Fortran needed by NumPy and SciPy and is not maintained.

Thanks for your answer.  This is bad news then?  How can I find related questions and advice? Would you have a link for me?

You find them by using the search field at the top. I have very little time but check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983850/f2py-access-module-parameter-from-subroutine/36439567#36439567  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515463/f2py-doesnt-like-explicit-shaped-array-in-subroutine/15805718#15805718

For the latest F2PY (numpy 1.26 & 2.0), the following workarounds are needed for your fortran code:

F2PY 1.26 & 2.0 seems to work fine with the parameters in the modules;
Return an array of type np.float128 (long double), probably platform-dependent;

mapfile.txt:
{'real': {'10': "long_double"}, 'integer': {'c_int': "int"}}

240616-test-2_0.f90:
module CHEMISTRY
  integer, parameter :: NMOLE = 20
end module CHEMISTRY

program main
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  real*8 :: T
  !NMOLE = 20
  T = 1000.0
  call CHECK_MELTING(T)
end program main

subroutine CHECK_MELTING(T)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 18, 4931 )     ! np.float128
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  call SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
  print *, NMOLE, T, Sat
end subroutine CHECK_MELTING

subroutine SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 18, 4931 )     ! np.float128
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp),intent(out) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  Sat(1:NMOLE) = 1.2_qp
end subroutine SUPERSAT

Result:
$ f2py --f2cmap mapfile.txt -m ggchemlib -c 240616-test-2_0.f90
...
$ python -c "import ggchemlib; print(ggchemlib.__doc__); s=ggchemlib.supersat(1000.); print(s.dtype, s)"
This module 'ggchemlib' is auto-generated with f2py (version:2.0.0).
Functions:
    check_melting(t)
    sat = supersat(t)
.
float128 [1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2
 1.2 1.2]

Alternately, if need modules variables, next workaround:
240616-testb.f90:
module CHEMISTRY
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
      ! bind to `extern int nmole`
  integer(C_INT), bind(C) :: NMOLE
      ! python can't call main
  data NMOLE/10/
end module CHEMISTRY

program main
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  real*8 :: T
  print *, NMOLE
  NMOLE = 20
  T = 1000.0
  call CHECK_MELTING(T)
end program main

subroutine CHECK_MELTING(T)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 18, 4931 )     ! np.float128
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  call SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
  print *, NMOLE, T, Sat
  print *, 'qp=', qp, digits(Sat(1)), epsilon(Sat(1)), huge(Sat(1))
end subroutine CHECK_MELTING

subroutine SUPERSAT(T,Sat)
  use CHEMISTRY,ONLY: NMOLE
      ! Workaround F2PY limitations with a pseudo comment
  !f2py usercode extern int nmole;
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind ( 18, 4931 )     ! np.float128
  real*8,intent(in) :: T
  real(kind=qp),intent(out) :: Sat(NMOLE)
  Sat(1:NMOLE) = 1.23456789_qp
end subroutine SUPERSAT

Result:
$ python3.11 -m numpy.f2py --f2cmap mapfile.txt -m ggchemlib -c 240616-testb.f90 
...
$ python3.11 -c "import ggchemlib; print(ggchemlib.__doc__); s=ggchemlib.supersat(1000.); print(s.dtype, s)"
This module 'ggchemlib' is auto-generated with f2py (version:1.24.2).
Functions:
    check_melting(t)
    sat = supersat(t)
Fortran 90/95 modules:
  chemistry --- nmole.
float128 [1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789
 1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789 1.23456789]


Thanks!  However, why did you change selected_real_kind to (18, 4931)?  I need FORTTRAN quad precision arithmetic s, and some of the solvers I use require (33,4931).

@pw31, selected_real_kind to (18, 4931) or less is required for all variables and arrays that interact with python since F2PY & NumPy only support float, double and long double. However, variables and arrays that will never be accessed from python can have any types.

@pw31, for example, if you will only call CHECK_MELTING() from python, then you can do it in one of the following ways: 1. Get (create) a .pyf file by removing the interface for SUPERSAT() from it; 2. Move SUPERSAT() to a separate file(module) and/or library; 3. Just fictitiously add to mapfile.txt description {'16': "long_double"}, but never call SUPERSAT() from python.
